# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria, in-subquery

I am trying to run a subquery in hibernate like this:-

```
DetachedCriteria cartProductIds = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserCart.class,"usercart")
                                        .add(Restrictions.eq("is_deleted", false))
                                        .add(Property.forName("usercart.user_id").eq(Property.forName("search.userId")))
                                        .add(Property.forName("usercart.product_id").eq(Property.forName("search.productId")))
                                        .setProjection(Projections.property("product_id"));

List<SearchHistory> history=session.createCriteria(SearchHistory.class,"search")
                                .add(Restrictions.between("creationTime", startTime, Timings.getCurrentTime()))
                                .add(Restrictions.eq("notification_send", false))
                                .add(Subqueries.notIn("productId", cartProductIds))
                                .list();
```

But there is a error on notIn subquery line which shows as :-

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long.`

Need help to solve this issue.Thanks!

Comment: what is in `cartProductIds` ?

Comment: please add complete error stacktrace to identify the problem... Thanks :)

Comment: I think your cartProductIds returning List<String> but your productId column variable is Long type. So convert your List<String> to List<Long>.

Comment: You can try `.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("productId", cartProductIds)`

Comment: Thanks got it working now.